# sonata admin bundle: nested set

Tags: symfony, nested-sets, sonata-admin

I have entity Location that is nested-set and it will have about 6 million records. Entity Property is many to one with Location.

Unfortunatelly, sonata doesn't suport nested set. So instead of having  with 6mill options, is there a way I could implement auto-completion for that field?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the nested set behaviour is possible in Sonata through [3pp4rd / DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) (see Tree extension) and the Autocomplete feature in Sonata is delivered with this [genemu / GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle) bundle which integrates the jQuery autocompleter.
Both bundles will guide you on how to implement it.